# Connecting nearby coordinates from list of coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, line, scatter-plot

I have the following list of latitudes and longitudes.

`[(52.5, 12.0), (36.0, -0.5), (50.0, -17.5), (52.0, 13.0), (52.0, 13.0), (50.0, -16.5), (37.5, 1.5), (37.5, 1.5), (46.0, 20.0), (37.5, 1.5), (46.0, 20.0), (50.0, -15.0)]`

I wish to connect only the points that are near each other. I would like to also only connect if the index difference between each point is less than 5 (for example).

I was initially looking for a method of connecting all points only if the line drawn is under a certain length. Not sure if this is possible in python?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by index difference? Difference between the x coordinate, y coordinate, Euclidean distance?
What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does index distance wrap? For instance, is 5 before the first element include the last element?

Comment: What does your code look like so far? : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Many thanks for such quick responses!

By index, I mean place in the list of (lat,lons). So (52.5, 12.0) would return index 0, (36.0, -0.5) would return index 1 etc.

Comment: Is there no way of assessing the the line length before connecting scatter points? Or perhaps even just setting longer lines to colour 'none'?

Comment: How do you define "near"? Like United States to Canada near, or Mexico to Australia near? No less than 50 miles? 1000?

Comment: Let's consider (50.0, -16.5) and (50.0, -17.5) near. So within a few hundred kilometres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes indexes wrap and that 'near' is defined as 1 units. For each element in the list, performs a distance check on the 10 surrounding elements, and if they are within 1 of each other, adds to a dictionary.

```
nearby = {}                                                          # This will hold 'connected' elements
for index, element in enumerate(l):                                  # Enumerate through the list l, keeping track of index
    for other in l[index-5: index+5]:                                # For each element 5 before and 5 after
        if sum( (a - b)**2 for a, b in zip(element, other))**.5 < 1 and element != other: 
                                                                     # If other < 5 away from element and other not element
            if element not in nearby.keys():                         # If element isn't already in the dicitonary
                nearby[element] = [other]                            # Add it and reference other
            else:                                                    # Otherwise
                nearby[element].append(other)                        # Add other to the list of nearby elements
```

If indexes don't wrap you can change the line `for other in l[index-5: index+5]:` to include checks for the beginning and end of the list. Here's how I would do it:

```
for other in l[index-5 if index-5 > 0 else 0 : index+5 if index+5 < len(l) else len(l) -1]:
```

This is quite long, so you may want to split this into several lines, but it does the trick as is.

Comment: Consider changing the <1 to <100 given that the OP has commented that he considers ~100 to be near, and also, your code when run as is currently results in an empty dict.

Comment: ~100 is in kilometers, his points are in latitude and longitude, so <100 would be most of the world, I believe. Also I'm almost certain it does not. I have tested it on my machine and TIO and it works in both places.

Comment: https://tio.run/##hZDdboMwDIXv8xTeXdKFKMDSStXYiyAuguqqaBAQUGls2rOz/LGq06b5Bh/8@djOsMyX3uTr2kJRUpUJxSHNhGQcaL4XkkMihXJKSa/SQ5SZk2ke0B8qovuA5gfv@ot48hMyGef9XdoclZUVIQb1WC9QwMcnOfcjNOaEbxywxQ7NbCWguXY46hlpy44EbDiuny/oaGhL35IoaM6wpS8grcWE9nMMPx9vdZs@Q4vG@gUo5klaBX8XFp6uHQWqIYGa7XaZH6s51G7qezPQuCMPuzDLCOesQJvT9wEPRSjfnKP7BpjeXxneQbziMlF2D7sI5TI2Vfa9Sm9b3ZHumn97hR4GNCcatiZkGBsz0wCxdf0C